# Create a disable CheckBox with same appearance in enable state

Tags: wpf, devexpress

I want create ckeckbox in devexpress with same appearance in enable state.

Comment: Because that won't be confusing or unintuitive for users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code:

```
 <Grid>
     <dxe:CheckEdit HorizontalAlignment="Left"  />
     <Label Background="Transparent"/>
 </Grid>
```